# How to read from terminal stream in java GUI application?

Tags: java, .net, console, terminal

I have a hardware system that will be writing to the terminal stream.  I need to be able to monitor that stream for updates (writes) from my java application.  How can I do this?  I've only ever interacted with the terminal in a pure console application.

I could also write my application in .Net languages, so I'll accept answers for .NET as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you launch the GUI program from command line, you get the terminal input stream with [System.in](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in).

If you don't, ther's no java way, in my opinion.